# How to encode Live Streaming using NReco.VideoConverter?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-streaming, live-streaming, video-encoding

I'm developing an application to encode a live stream using NReco.VideoConverter component. I'm getting a live video stream from one of my IP cameras, and it uses rtsp. The url is "rtsp://test.vaprtech.com/vid/show.sav?[PARAMETERS]". Now the code I use is given below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String path="rtsp://test.vaprtech.com/vid/show.sav?[PARAMETERS]";
        String pathToSave="C:\\Videos\\LiveVideo.mp4";
        var ffMpeg = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();
        ConvertLiveMediaTask task=ffMpeg.ConvertLiveMedia(path, Format.mp4, pathToSave, Format.mp4, new ConvertSettings(){VideoCodec="h264"});
        task.Start();
}
```

But I'm getting an error saying

> "The best overloaded method match for
>   '...ConvertLiveMedia(string,string,System.IO.Stream,string,ConvertSettings)'
>   has some invalid arguments".

Comment: `pathToSave` is `string` but looks like this method expect `Stream` as a third parameter and that's why you get this error.

Comment: @Soner Gönül Yeah.. You're right. Can you tell me, instead of giving a local path, how can I use `Stream` to get the encoded video and save it so that I could stream it later ?